# Wiring sets of 2, 15" LED strips to illuminated switch. 12 sets total -- to power supply

Tags: power-supply, power, led

Ok, Hoping you guys can help me. I have a screen printing machine for printing t-shirts. The machine has 12 arms that extend out from the center. Under each of these arms I want to put 2 15" white LED strips. So in total it would be 24 total strips. Each set of 2 strips would be powered by an illuminated push button switch on the end of the arm. My question is can I use one central power supply at the center of the machine to power all 24 strips? If so, can you recommend one. Or any other ideas how to complete this project. TIA

Comment: Shopping questions are forbidden, so you can't ask for a product recommendation in the way you have.  The disadvantage of using LEDs in parallel off a common power supply is that you still have to provide current control for each LED.  As a result, we need to know exactly what strips you're thinking of, as some will include series resistors that provide current control, while more efficient ones will require individual current control.  Depending on which of those is the case, you will likely need a voltage regulator plus possibly a constant current regulator for each arm.

Answer (score 0):

24 x 15" / 39.6 ["/m] = 9.09 m or two 5m reels.  There are many grades of colour, brightness and Watts/m.  But I suspect any PC PSU can power this off the 12V rail drawing about 25W to 75 W total depending on W/m specs.